# Conditionally append string to rows in a Pandas dataframe based on presence of values in another column

Tags: python, qt, pandas, twitter

I'm working with tweets in a Pandas dataframe (Python). I'm trying to indicate that a specific tweet is a 'quoted tweet' by:

1) Looking at whether the 'quoted_author' field is blank or not

2) If the field is NOT blank, add the following prefix in front of the tweet text that includes the quoted author's username:

*'QT @[quoted_author]: [tweet text]'*

This is the code that is not working for me. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
for row in df['quoted_author']:
        if row == "":
            pass
        else:
            df['Text'].append('QT ' + df['quoted_author'].astype(str) + ': ' + df['Text'].astype(str))
```

Comment: Can you post sample data?

Answer (score 1):

Another one-liner solution

**Setup (using Andrew L's example)**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'quoted_author': {0: 'person1',
  1: 'person2',  2: '',  3: '',  4: 'author',  5: 'some_author'}, 'text': {0: 'tweettext',
  1: 'somethingtweeted',  2: 'fooootext',  3: 'sometweets',  4: 'atweet',  5: 'someothertweet'}})
```

**Solution**

```
#use apply to reset test column based on the value of quoted_author. 
df.text = df.apply(lambda x: 'QT {}: {}'.format(x.quoted_author, x.text) if x.quoted_author else x.text, axis=1)

  quoted_author                            text
0       person1           QT person1: tweettext
1       person2    QT person2: somethingtweeted
2                                     fooootext
3                                    sometweets
4        author               QT author: atweet
5   some_author  QT some_author: someothertweet
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping over every row and finding if it's equal to null or not,try to get all the rows that are not null.

`df_author = df[df['quoated author'] != ""]`

Then use apply function to append all the rows of df_author with corresponding author names.

Answer (score 0):

I went through and evaluated two different methods of achieving this. The first involves using apply and a separate function. See below:

```
df
      quoted_author        tweet_text
    0       person1         tweettext
    1       person2  somethingtweeted
    2           NaN         fooootext
    3           NaN        sometweets
    4        author            atweet
    5   some_author    someothertweet
```

Method 1- Function and apply:

```
def nullCheck(author, tweet):
    if not pd.isnull(author):
        return 'QT ' + str(author) + ': ' + str(tweet)
    else:
        return np.nan


df['output'] = df[['quoted_author', 'tweet_text']].apply(lambda x: nullCheck(*x), axis=1)

%timeit df['output'] = df[['quoted_author', 'tweet_text']].apply(lambda x: nullCheck(*x), axis=1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.01 ms per loop
```

Method 2- Slice the dataframe to only view non-null authors then produce output in separate column:

```
df.loc[~pd.isnull(df['quoted_author']),'output'] = 'QT ' + df['quoted_author'] + ': ' + df['tweet_text']

%timeit df.loc[~pd.isnull(df['quoted_author']),'output'] = 'QT ' + df['quoted_author'] + ': ' + df['tweet_text']
    1000 loops, best of 3: 1.68 ms per loop
```

Interestingly the first method is faster though I'm not exactly sure why. Can anyone else share some insight on this? Either way this will get you what you're looking for.